# Extract value from FILENAME in awk and use it as a new field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm working on CSV file named `Event_42417555_2018-05-23_16\:45\:28-log.txt` and formatted like this:

```
timestamp;fullpath;event;size
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_OPEN;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_ACCESS;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_OPEN;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_ACCESS;2160
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2160
```

What I want is to add a column to this file based on a value in the filename extracted with regex `[0-9]{8}` (and remove the header).

```
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_OPEN;2324;42417555
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_ACCESS;2324;42417555
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2324;42417555
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_OPEN;2160;42417555
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_ACCESS;2160;42417555
1521540649.03;/home/workdir/quad_list_14.json;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2160;42417555
```

With gnu tools it's easy it would be like this (barely tested and almost sure there a problem with quotes somehow):

```
#!/bin/bash
#$1 being the filename
JOBID=$(grep -oE "[0-9]{8}" "${1}")
sed -E "s/(.*)/\1;$JOBID/" "${1}"
```

I want to achieve this in `awk` so far here what worked *the best*:

```
awk -F";"  'JOBID=substr(FILENAME ,match(FILENAME,"[0-9]{8}"),8); \  
BEGIN { OFS=";"} { if ($1 != "timestamp") print $0,JOBID; }' \  
Event_42417555_2018-05-23_16\:45\:28-log.txt | head

timestamp;fullpath;event;size
timestamp;fullpath;event;size
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_OPEN;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_OPEN;2324;42417555
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_ACCESS;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_ACCESS;2324;42417555
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2324
1521540649.02;/home/workdir/ScienceXMLIn/config.cfg;IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE;2324;42417555
```

I have my variable and it set properly, but I can't find the proper position for it.
If I move the `JOBID=substr(FILENAME ,match(FILENAME,"[0-9]{8}"),8);`
I can't manage to access the variable.
The problem here being that the file is processed two time, one properly (though my condition is ignored) and the other one where it considered my variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it’s a property of each file, you should calculate `JOBID` when processing the first line of any file, *i.e.* when `FNR` is 1:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
FNR == 1 { JOBID=substr(FILENAME, match(FILENAME, "[0-9]{8}"), 8); print }
FNR > 1 { print $0, JOBID }' \
Event_42417555_2018-05-23_16\:45\:28-log.txt | head
```

There are a number of ways of extracting a match for a regular expression; I would typically `match` into an array:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
FNR == 1 { match(FILENAME, "([0-9]{8})", a); JOBID = a[1]; print }
FNR > 1 { print $0, JOBID }' \
Event_42417555_2018-05-23_16\:45\:28-log.txt | head
```

ideally with some error handling. This uses `match` to look for text matching `[0-9]{8}`, and extracts any matching values into the array `a` (`match` looks for groups, hence the added parentheses).

Another approach which should work in any AWK implementation is to split the filename on underscores:

```
awk -F";" 'BEGIN { OFS = FS }
FNR == 1 { split(FILENAME, a, "_"); JOBID = a[2]; print }
FNR > 1 { print $0, JOBID }' \
Event_42417555_2018-05-23_16\:45\:28-log.txt | head
```

The doubled output in your version happens because `JOBID=substr(FILENAME ,match(FILENAME,"[0-9]{8}"),8)` is a complete expression with the same weight as any other in your AWK program, with an implicit block (*i.e.* `print`); it always matches, because `JOBID` is always non-empty and not a numeric value equal to zero, so its block is always processed.

Comment: Is this the correct way to extract regex from a variable I couldn't find any thing better

Comment: `mawk` and BSD `awk` both fail to match the number from the filename, while GNU `awk` succeeds.

Comment: @Kusalananda good thing I'm using a GNU `awk`